# MYSQLI prepared statement bind_param types does not work

Tags: php, mysql

I have been using prepared insert statements for some years and assumed it was binding parameters properly or would give an error but it seems not as the following php binds and inserts a record without any errors but changes a string which should be an int to a zero. So it may be ok for preventing SQL injection attacks but you would end up with a spurious record in the table. e.g.:

```
    $q = "INSERT INTO `table` (id1, id2) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($dbc);
    $stmt->prepare($q);
    $id1 = 'aaaaaaa';
    $id2= 'aaaaaaa';
    $result = $stmt->bind_param('ii', $id1, $id2);
    echo '<p>' . $result . '</p>'; // Trying to bind a string to an int returns true! 
    echo $dbc->error; // nothing
    $stmt->execute(); // inserts record changing $id2 to zero but auto-increments primary key $id1
    echo $dbc->error; // nothing
```

This is running in an Xampp environment with Apache/2.2.14, PHP/5.3.1 and MySQL 5.1.41. Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Comment: I think you want to check the stmt error - `$stmt->error` not the db connection error `$dbc->error`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. $stmt->error doesn't give an error but that is expected since bind_param returns true. The bind_param error reporting is clearly naff!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert for sure, but at first look.
You have:

```
$id1 = 'aaaaaaa';
$id2= 'aaaaaaa';
$result = $stmt->bind_param('ii', $id1, $id2);
```

Thing is your `'ii'` parameter says that you will be binding integers! And in fact your `$id1` and `$id2` are strings. For strings you should go with:

```
$result = $stmt->bind_param('ss', $id1, $id2);
```

Answer (score 0):

$stmt->bind_param() doesn't check the given variables for a certain type, it only converts them into the specified type. And your string 'aaaaaaa' is converted into an int-value: 0. That's the way php does it.

The database insert statement is the wrong place to check, if your variables contain useful/correct values. Do that before and only try to insert them, if your validations work.

To do the validation for an int, you could use the php-function is_numeric() or is_int().